# R (and Bioconductor) cant install packages "path not writable/access denied"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using R again after some time and need to install various packages (e.g. lumi, GENAVi, ideal, limma) and for some the installation works for some not. I receive failure notifications indicating that I the library paths are not writable or that access is denied.

[installation of lumi with bioconductor fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcv6Q.png)
[thus, lumi appears to be not existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AEyY.png)

My PC uses windows 10, recently updated, and R 4.1.1

I tried the following steps (based on older forum entries):

1. I ran R Studio with administrator permissions
2. I gave R full permission through the firewall of my antivirus program
3. I gave R permission through the windows security settings
4. I reinstalled R on another harddrive (E:/) where it should have full permission for all paths.
5. I added a path in the xxx
6. I ran R inside a new environment in the “Conda” software, but the permission problems persisted.
7. (Outside of Conda) I installed the lumi package out of a zip file (instead of a Bioconductor download). Still didnt work...
   So I now don’t know what to do anymore and barely find new ideas for solving the problem.

I appreciate your help

Comment: Use R function `.libPaths()` to indicate where packages were installed into. then, go to the Windows explorer and check if you are able to write into this folder (right click, properties, Security).

Comment: I used that command. To the first library (C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/4.1 i had full permissions and to the second "E:/R-4.1.1/library"   i added all permissions and it still didnt work.

Comment: According to your image, the package methylumi is also not installed. In case of wired issues one can also try to put the software in isolated docker containers. Then you don't have side effects with your usual Operating system and the container is portable to other systems.

Comment: Usually dependencies (like methylumi e.g.) are installed automatically. But it didnt work out now. Which isolated container would you recommend? Conda? I tried it, didnt work but I also dodnt really customize it.

Comment: I often use the rocker docker images as a start https://github.com/BillMills/Rocker-tutorial. Conda does not isolate everything to your environment and is known to have issues in package resolvement. It is also not recommended to install R packages from both CRAN and conda.